# Users still have access to Outlook Web Access after disabling account or changing password

Tags: microsoft-office-365

I have changed a user's password, but it seems that he was logged in via webmail at the time, and he his session has remained alive.

I have disabled the account too at the time of active session on webmail but still the users has a active session.

Comment: If the answers you were provided help you with your question, you should select one as an accepted answer.

Answer (score 4):

The web session doesn't become invalid when the account changes, unfortunately. Same thing happens if you have a user logged into a domain workstation and you disable their account. They still have a valid session on that workstation and won't notice a problem until they have to reauthenticate to that machine (logout/login or unlock), or need to access resources on another machine that they don't have a current session on.

Answer (score 2):

What mfinni said.  One possible workaround may be to turn off the user's access to OWA via PowerShell with `Set-Mailbox -Identity "user's ID" -OWAEnabled $false`.  If you're using ADFS, you might be able to [create an AD group which is not allowed to remotely access Office 365](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh526961%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) and put terminated employees there.

I don't know if either will kick them out before their session expires, however, and am not in a position to test it.

Answer (score 0):

OWA and ActiveSync have similar issues: an auth request does not go through for every data request. A user will have a token which has a TTL. :(

There are two *extremely relevant* articles in Technet Blogs:

Part I: [ActiveSync](http://blogs.technet.com/b/messaging_with_communications/archive/2012/06/26/activesync-disabled-accounts-and-devices-continuing-to-sync.aspx)

Part II: [OWA, MAPI & EWS](http://blogs.technet.com/b/messaging_with_communications/archive/2012/06/27/part-ii-outlook-amp-owa-disabled-accounts-and-users-still-being-able-to-access.aspx)

Even the approaches above are not instantaneous. However, 5-10 minutes is better than HOURS.